# Bootstrap-vue pagination is removing items from array

Tags: vue.js, pagination, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use Bootstrap-vue pagination component but it's not working. I went to the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination) and just tried to use their example:

```
<template>
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="my-table"
    ></b-pagination>

    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

    <b-table
      id="my-table"
      :items="items"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        perPage: 3,
        currentPage: 1,
        items: [
          { id: 1, first_name: 'Fred', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 2, first_name: 'Wilma', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 3, first_name: 'Barney', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 4, first_name: 'Betty', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 5, first_name: 'Pebbles', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 6, first_name: 'Bamm Bamm', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 7, first_name: 'The Great', last_name: 'Gazzoo' },
          { id: 8, first_name: 'Rockhead', last_name: 'Slate' },
          { id: 9, first_name: 'Pearl', last_name: 'Slaghoople' }
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
        return this.items.length
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and this is happening:

[image]

I just copied the documentation example and it's not working. My project uses Vue 3.3.4 and bootstrap-vue-3 (^0.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, click "Getting Started" in the left navigation bar. You'll be able to read:

> - Vue.js `v2.6` is required, `v2.6.12` is recommended
> - Bootstrap `v4.3.1` is required, `v4.6.1` is recommended
> - ...

If you want to use `bootstrap-vue` with Vue 3, click the "Vue 3" link in the top bar and follow instructions. However, it is not guaranteed everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap-vue-3` is deprecated and a separate project entirely to the documentation you've linked.

`bootstrap-vue-3` was renamed to `bootstrap-vue-next`, which you can find [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue-next/bootstrap-vue-next), along with the proper documentation.